# Second Navigation bar not working when scroll in Internet Explorer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, navigation, affix

We have 2 navigation bars on one page and they both fully work in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. With IE, they work only part of the time. When the page loads, they both work, but once the user starts scrolling the second one stops working until it is affixed to the top and replaces the first one and then it works again. See the page here:

http://www.sosc.org/new/orangecounty

I'm thinking it has something to do with Bootstrap affix? Like I said, the page functions fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `.mainDiv` element is 602px tall, and overlaps the second navigation. You cannot click *through* `.mainDiv`, so you cannot click the navigation beneath it. The height of this element is unnecessarily large; if you set it to 480px, you will resolve the issue.

You can see the same issue in Chrome as well - move your mouse down from above the second menu. The top 25% of the menu will not recognize your mouse as hovering it. The lower 3/4 or so will.

Below is Chrome 43 demonstrating the same issue:

[image]

Comment: Fixed!  I guess these issues are what I get for taking over for a flaky web designer 75% of the way through a redesign. Thanks for the help!